# java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to create a simple SQLite database program that could create a database, a table, insert and retrieve data. How can I fix this? I keep getting the exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: statement is not executing

```
package databaseproj;

import java.sql.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            String sDriverName = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
            Class.forName(sDriverName);
            String dbURL= "jdbc:sqlite:hello.db";

            Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            Statement st= conn.createStatement();

            String createtable="CREATE TABLE contacts(name text, number numeric, email text)";
            System.out.println("Table created successfully");
            String insertcontacts="INSERT INTO contacts(name, number, email) VALUES('nduka',08166459353,'ndukaude')";

            st.executeUpdate(createtable);
            st.executeUpdate(insertcontacts);
            System.out.println("Insert complete");

            ResultSet rs= st.getResultSet(); 

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            while ( rs.next() ){
                String name= rs.getString("name");
                int num=rs.getInt("number");
                String email=rs.getString("email");

                System.out.println("NAME: "+name);
                System.out.println("NUMBER: "+ num);
                System.out.println("EMAIL: "+email);
            }

            conn.commit();
            conn=null;
            System.out.println("connection emptied");
            rs.close();

            st.close();

            conn.close();
            System.out.println("connection closed");
        }

        catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which statement is failing to execute?

Comment: If "number" is a phone number, you probably want to insert it as a varchar, not a numeric value .

Comment: is autocommit true in your case? otherwise you will not find the created table after execute the create sql

Comment: ResultSet rs= st.getResultSet(); does not execute

Answer (score 1):

use `execute(createtable)` instead `executeUpdate(createtable)`

Answer (score 0):

Dont know whether you found the solution.
The reason for this is most probably that the statement (`st`) is still referring to `Create Command` when you call `st.executeUpdate(insertcontacts)`.

Try to reinitialize the statement and run the insert command. It should work now!